# Multiple select queries using one table (improve performance)

Tags: mysql, performance

Is there a way to improve this query?

```
 SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait WHERE variety_id IN
 (SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait WHERE trait_id = 10 and trait_value =     2 and variety_id IN 
 (SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait WHERE trait_id = 9 and trait_value = 1 and variety_id IN 
 (SELECT variety_id FROM anvariety_trait WHERE trait_id = 7 and trait_value = 1 )))
```

I am trying to get the one result of three levels of select queries from the same table. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try join clauses, and a distinct, but I'm not sure this would improve your performances (worth a test, anyway)

```
select distinct v1.variety_id 
FROM anvariety_trait v1
join anvariety_trait v2 on v1.variety_id = v2.variety_id
join anvariety_trait v3 on v2.variety_id = v3.variety_id
join anvariety_trait v4 on v3.variety_id = v4.variety_id
where v2.trait_id = 10 and v2.trait_value = 2
and   v3.trait_id = 9  and v3.trait_value = 1
and   v4.trait_id = 7  and v4.trait_value = 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Works like a charm. ;)

Comment: @Sandy Pabilonia As an sidenote: You can boost performance even more when you have an key on `variety_id` and `trait_value` like this`KEY(variety_id, trait_value)`this way mysql doesnt need to use an join buffer and an temporary table for the distinct

Comment: Assuming this is InnoDB, I would recommend `INDEX(trait_id, trait_value, variety_id)`.

Comment: I doubt if `DISTINCT` is needed.

Comment: @RickJames distinct was needed in order for me to get the unique value

Comment: @RickJames putting index indeed made the query faster. thanks.